# How to separate 2 PHP apps running on same server from using a common session

Tags: php, session

I have 2 separate PHP apps running on the same domain server:  abc.com/demo & abc.com/live

There is session_start() on almost every PHP page in both these apps. As soon as a single user interacts with the second app, the first app freezes or stops working. I think the same session ID is being used by both, which causes this conflict.

I read on PHP manual that specifying the PHP session name like

```
session_name("DEMO");
```

or
session_name("LIVE"); may help.

My question is, do I need to specify the session_name on each and every PHP page in both the apps, or is only required when the session is first created, during the login success process.

Kindly advise. Thanks.

Comment: I want to know what you mean by 2 PHP apps.

Comment: @MdZahid no matter if it's really "2 PHP apps" or "same app's production-mode", the answers remain the same ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"On each and every ... page" is the right way.

But separate it into another script, and include that in other scripts.

### Example

Because you name your sessions "DEMO" and "LIVE",
maybe place logic to decide session in a file which is shared and/or used by both apps.

```php
$isProduction = ...;

session_name($isProduction ? "LIVE" : "DEMO");
session_start();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that your number of PHP files and you want to access some value that is stored in the PHP session then you should session_start(); for every file

> **You can separate your session like this**

```
session_name($isAPP_ONE ? "APP_ONE" : "APP_TWO");
```

like store_session.php

```
session_start();

$_SESSSION["username"] = "Md Zahidul Islam";
```

home.php

```
session_start();

$_SESSSION["username"]; // this will give you Md Zahidul Islam
```

home-two.php

```
session_start();

$_SESSSION["username"]; // this will give you Md Zahidul Islam
```

> **And if you use work like this, then there is no need to use session_start(); on every file.**

like header.php

```
session_start();
```

home.php

```
include("header.php");

$_SESSSION["username"]; // this will return you Md Zahidul Islam and this value will come from the store_session.php file
```

home-two.php

```
include("header.php");

$_SESSSION["username"]; // this will return you Md Zahidul Islam and this value will come from the store_session.php file
```

Comment: These are 2 completely separate apps. So if a session variable name happens to be same, it should not get passed from 1 app to another. So I found out that we need to add the session_name("AAA"); and session_Name("BBB") on each and every page of both apps, respectively. Will try this in production to see if it works!

Comment: You can separate your session like this

session_name($isAPP_ONE ? "APP_ONE" : "APP_TWO");